# Пунктуация, если цитата не является самостоятельным предложением

Tags: пунктуация, цитата, многоточие

Хотелось бы разобраться с постановкой знаков препинания в случае, если цитата включена в авторское предложение на правах его компонента и не является самостоятельным предложением. Читаю Розенталя ([§ 56. Многоточие при цитатах](http://%C2%A7%2056.%20%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85)) и Лопатина ([Знаки препинания при цитатах](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139)). Правильно ли я понимаю, что если цитируется срединная часть предложения (не с начала и не до конца), то многоточие в начале цитаты не ставится, но ставится в конце? Почему в следующем примере нет многоточия:

> Новые законы для столичной экономики, как сказал Олег Михайлович "выгодны, удобны и полезны". [Светлана Бударцева. Красная площадь не продается (2002) // «Вечерняя Москва», 2002.03.14]

Возможно, правило о постановке многоточия не такое уж строгое?

Вот такой пример.

> Мне кажется, что стиль перевода не будет нарушен, если мы в меру и с тактом будем в своем переводе передавать иностранные пословицы и поговорки русскими, особенно в тех случаях, когда буквальный перевод неуклюж и многословен (Чуковский).

Я пишу: <<Чуковский писал, что передавая при переводе иностранные пословицы и поговорки русскими, нужно это делать "в меру и с тактом">>.

Должен ли я ставить многоточие?

Answer (score 2):

> Я пишу: <<Чуковский писал, что передавая при переводе иностранные
>   пословицы и поговорки русскими, нужно это делать "в меру и с
>   тактом">>.
>
> Должен ли я ставить многоточие?

Многоточие - нет, так как цитируются несколько слов (как и в первом цитатопримере). Нужна запятая перед деепричастием "передавая"!

Многоточие требуется, когда цитируется предложение, но не с начала!

> Как пишет К. Чуковский, "...каждая чеховская новелла так лаконична,
>   так густа по своей консистенции... что если бы кто-нибудь вздумал
>   прокомментировать любую из них, комментарии оказались бы гораздо
>   обширнее текста..."

Оригинальный текст Чуковского:

> Вообще каждая чеховская новелла так лаконична, так густа по своей
>   консистенции, образы в ней так многосмысленны, что если бы кто-нибудь
>   вздумал прокомментировать любую из них, комментарии оказались бы
>   гораздо обширнее текста, ибо иному беглому и малозаметному образу,
>   занимающему в тексте две строки, пришлось бы посвятить пять-шесть
>   страниц, чтобы хоть отчасти дознаться, какая идея заключается в нем.

**[источник](http://genling.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000026/st055.shtml)**